# Folding a paper in half - Crease Lines

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A strip of paper is folded in half, then the result is folded in half again, and the process is repeated for a total of 6 times (including the first fold). How many creases (fold lines) are there?

Comment: What are your own thoughts on the problem? Can you answer the question how many creases there are after just one or two folds? Actually folding a piece of paper might also help to gain some intuition.

Comment: Consider making a table of values. How many creases are there after one fold? Two folds? Three? Can you see a pattern?

Comment: 1 Fold | 1 Crease  ....
2 Folds| 2 Creases ....
3 Folds| 4 Creases ....
4 Folds| 6 Creases ....

Comment: If you use real paper, do the folding, then open the paper and count fold lines, you will get other numbers.

Comment: @AndréNicolas if you use a real A4 paper, you will notice it will become very hard to fold the paper in 1 direction for the $6^{th}$ time. If you allow to fold the paper in 2 directions, you will get the number the OP mentions.

Comment: I am folding the paper in alternating directions - first fold from top to bottom, then next from left to right, then next from top to bottom, and so on. What are the numbers you obtained? Also, I continued folding and got this series - 1,2,4,6,10,14... which seems to be OEIS A000065 - the number of partitions of n.

Comment: @user2612743 Perhaps Andre was referring to folding the same direction over and over again. In that case, the numbers you get will be $1,3,7,15,$ etc. For alternating directions the problem is more fun of course.

Comment: For folding in alternate directions, the numbers are given by [OEIS A027383](http://oeis.org/A027383).

Comment: Ok. It seems that there is no easy formula for the alternating. After some more folding I got the series 1,2,4,6,10,14,22,30,46 - which matches with OEIS A027383. 

EDIT: It seems I was a bit late to figure that out :P. What about for folding in the same direction? Any series for that?

Comment: $$2^n - 1\quad\text{ and }\quad2^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor} + 2^{\lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil} - 2$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can be more than one answer.

If I keep folding the paper in half in the same direction $f$ times, I get $2^f-1$

[image: Case 1]

If however, you change the line along which you fold (like if you fold from top to bottom the 1st time, and from left to right the second time), the answer will depend on how you count the creases.

[image: Case 2]

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: So it seems that the problem itself is too general and there are multiple cases. Thanks for taking the time to do the drawing!